# Ubuntu 16.04 fails to resume from suspend when on battery

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I am using an Asus UX303U. When I am plugged into to main socket, resume works. Otherwise the laptop starts afresh with the system boot screen.

Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux